# How to refactor this one function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two functions which is meant to add/remove data to an endpoint. I currently have two functions one with add data, and one with remove data.

```
 const addMultipleAuthorities = async () => {
    const postMultipleAuthoritiesData = {
      sid: selectedPerson,
      authorities: selectedAuth,
      action: 'add'
    }
    console.log(postMultipleAuthoritiesData);
  }

  const removeMultipleAuthorities = async () => {
    const removeMultipleAuthoritiesData = {
      sId: selectedPerson,
      authorities: selectedAuth,
      action: 'remove'
    }
    console.log(removeMultipleAuthoritiesData)
  }
```

These are both called on seperate buttons....I was wondering how I can make this code with one function as I seem to be repeating myself atm..

Here are the two buttons which are calling the functions

```
 <Button
        text='Add Authorities'
        className='Button Dark Main'
        onClick={addMultipleAuthorities}
 />



 <Button
         text='Remove Authorities'
          className='Button Dark Main'
          onClick={removeMultipleAuthorities}
     />
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is currying (what CertainPerformance has in their answer)

Another possibility is to set an attribute on the button that you use in the handler:

In this I'm using a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) (any data-* attribute) as they are great for this sort of thing.

```
const clickHandler = async (e) => {
    const action = e.target.dataset.action;
    const removeMultipleAuthoritiesData = {
      sId: selectedPerson,
      authorities: selectedAuth,
      action
    }
    console.log(removeMultipleAuthoritiesData)
  }
```

```
 <Button
        text='Add Authorities'
        className='Button Dark Main'
        data-action="add"
        onClick={clickHandler}
 />



 <Button
         text='Remove Authorities'
          className='Button Dark Main'
          data-action="remove"
          onClick={clickHandler}
     />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function that, given the `action`, returns a function that logs the object:

```
const makeClickHandler = action => () => {
    const data = {
      sid: selectedPerson,
      authorities: selectedAuth,
      action,
    };
    console.log(data);
};
```

```
 <Button
        text='Add Authorities'
        className='Button Dark Main'
        onClick={makeClickHandler('add')}
 />



 <Button
         text='Remove Authorities'
          className='Button Dark Main'
          onClick={makeClickHandler('remove')}
     />
```

Comment: Hey @certainPerformance, thanks. Could you possible link me to a resource where you had used the makeClickHandler = action = () =>. Never new you could do that! Thanks

Comment: A resource? What do you mean?

Comment: sorry, hit enter when I was trying to type, just updated

Comment: The `makeClickHandler` is used in the `onClick` handlers - see the lower part of the answer.

Comment: Here's couple links that gives a bit of information on currying functions: https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-currying-in-javascript-ceb2188c339 and https://javascript.info/currying-partials - It's essentially just making a function return another function and using a closure to keep access to the variables.